# Iptables - Wifi Router User Sessions to OpenVPN in VM

Tags: iptables, openvpn, route, nat

The goal is to route wireless user sessions from a TP-Link TL-WR902AC Wifi travel router on the same LAN to an OpenVPN Client in a virtual machine.

My attempt at this is based on previous successful iptable routing between hostapd wlan0 and OpenVPN tun0 client in another system.

With the TP-Link router and OpenVPN Client the modified iptable commands don't work and I don't understand why. No surprise, in several areas I am guessing. Here is the set up.

```
192.168.0.1   Netgear LAN router to WAN
192.168.0.4   Linux Mint 19.3 Virtualbox host
192.168.0.6   Linux Mint Xfce VM with OpenVPN Client
192.168.0.7   TP-Link TL-WR902AC travel router
```

TP-Link router WAN settings

```
ip addr  192.168.0.7
gateway  192.168.0.6
DNS svr  192.168.0.6
```

TP-Link router LAN ip addr is 192.168.1.1

IPv4 forwarding enabled in the VM /etc/sysctl.conf

Routes on 192.168.0.6 VM:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway     Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.7.3.1    128.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 tun0
default         _gateway    0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 enp0s3
10.7.3.0        0.0.0.0     255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 tun0
128.0.0.0       10.7.3.1    128.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 tun0
link-local      0.0.0.0     255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 enp0s3
185.225.234.1   _gateway    255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 enp0s3
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0     255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 enp0s3
```

The iptables commands that don't work [except for being able to ping 10.7.3.1 from a wireless laptop - without the iptables loaded the ping fails]:

```
sudo /sbin/iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o tun0 -j MASQUERADE
sudo /sbin/iptables -A FORWARD -i enp0s3 -o tun0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
sudo /sbin/iptables -A FORWARD -i tun0 -o enp0s3 -j ACCEPT
```

Answer (score 0):

That pinging 10.7.3.1 was successful give me the idea that the DNS server address in the TP-Link router WAN settings might be the problem.

Tested it by changing it to the VPN server DNS address 103.86.96.100 then it worked.

Not bad, but I know that concerning iptables I'm still a beginner.